# Mostrar post_types ligados a uma taxonomia

Tags: php, wordpress

Como retornar todos os post_type vinculados a uma taxonomia?

Comment: Com SQL ou alguma função nativa do Wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forma rápida:

Supondo que sua taxonomia seja "pessoas" e a pessoa que você queira buscar seja "bob":

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'pessoas' => 'bob'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Outra forma de se fazer a mesma coisa...

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'pessoas',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'bob'
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Também é válido para buscar em mais de uma taxonomia:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'pessoas' => 'bob',
    'language' => 'english'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Está tudo no [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Answer (score 1):

Só usar o seguinte código e mudar a variável $type para o nome da sua taxonomia.

```
            $type = 'nomedataxonomia';
            $args=array(
              'post_type' => $type,
              'post_status' => 'publish',
              'posts_per_page' => -1,
            );


                $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                while ($my_query->have_posts()){
                      $my_query->the_post();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

A pergunta tem poucas informações, mas pelo que entendi você precisa listar posts (independente do tipo, se post, page ou outro que você criou), então no [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) temos a seguinte sugestão:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => 5,
'offset'           => 0,
'category'         => '',
'orderby'          => 'post_date',
'order'            => 'DESC',
'include'          => '',
'exclude'          => '',
'meta_key'         => '',
'meta_value'       => '',
'post_type'        => 'post',
'post_mime_type'   => '',
'post_parent'      => '',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true
 );
 ?>
```